# SSRS 2008 report file outputs incorrect TotalPages global variable

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a problem with a 2008 SSRS report file I'm creating. The test data I'm using outputs 2 pages for this report, but the global variable TotalPages seem to be getting an incorrect value, seen in the screenshot below.

[image: SSRS 2008 wrong TotalPages value showing]

Anyone have any ideas as to why this problem is happening..? I've come across a [Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2620333) that has albeit similar problem, but the article says the problem arose with an SSRS 2008 R2 report file, not an SSRS 2008 one. I also don't know if I can update the SQL server installation we have here.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ^^

Comment: please Delete the Cached Data by deleting <reportName>.rdl.data file from report source location and try it again; if you still getting same result then please share expression to get "Page 1 of 6"

Comment: I tried deleting the .data file. So when I previewed the report, I assume it would be correct that it would produce a new .data file, which it did. Still having the same problem though.. The expression I used for the page number was this: 

="Page " & Globals!PageNumber & " of " & Globals!TotalPages

Nothing special really.. Just used a bunch of strings and global variables..